# Azure Function with Javascript as http trigger language - missing function.json when generated via VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, function, visual-studio-code

I had created Azure Function with Javascript as the platform language. It works and deploys just fine. However, it's missing function.json. Is it expected to generated as I seen other posts having it. The reason I am asking this is because I need to add other dependencies (import modules) to write the code to connect to Azure Cosmo DB as an example.

Please let me point me the right path as I tried searching around but no luck for Azure Function with Javascript and if I do found them, they are older posts with function.json created automatically.

Thanks in advance.

I created a boilerplate using VS Code but missing function.json. Is this expected to be generated? It was shown on other tutorials and posts.

Answer: I fixed the function.json. It works for v3. I will try with v4 without using function.json and post it here if it works.

function.json for v3

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "test_DB",
      "collectionName": "test_container",
      "createIfNotExists": "false",
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDbConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack javascript in VS Code.

- While creating function if model4 take that will not give `function.josn`. Like below:

[image]

- While creating function will take function model3. it will generate `function.json` file. check below:

[image]

- After creating the function by followed above model getting like below:

[image]

**function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

- By using below function code successfully connected and sent data to CosmosDB by using database name and container names.
- primary key and Cosmos endpoint find like below:

[image]

**Function code:**

```
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const { CosmosClient } = require('@azure/cosmos');

const endpoint = 'Your cosmos URI';
const key = 'Your cosmos primary key';
const databaseId = 'sample';
const containerId = 'student';

const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });
const container = cosmosClient.database(databaseId).container(containerId);

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

        // Perform Cosmos DB operations
        const newItem = {
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: name
        };

        const { resource: createdItem } = await container.items.create(newItem);

        return { body: `Hello, ${createdItem.name}! Item created in Cosmos DB.` };
    }
});
```

[image]

By accessing the above URL getting response below:

[image]

The data can be visible in azure. check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Basically, v4 no longer provides function.json. If I need binding for Azure Cosmos DB, do I need to use v3 to have function.json being used?

Comment: If I use v4, how do I connect to the Azure Cosmos DB?

Comment: @KennyNg, Can you please tell which trigger your using in function app?

Comment: Can you refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-add-output-binding-cosmos-db-vs-code?tabs=isolated-process%2Cv1&pivots=programming-language-javascript).

Comment: @KennyNg, I have updated the above solution. Can you please check it will work.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation regardless. I was able to make it work using v3 and v4 connecting to Azure Cosmos DB.